Structure theorem for finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras
I'm looking for a proof of the fact that any finite-dimensional $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$
is isomorphic to
$$\mathcal{A} \cong M_{n_1} (\mathbb{C}) \oplus \cdots \oplus M_{n_k} (\mathbb{C})$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n_1, \dots, n_k \in \mathbb{N}$.
I proved that $\mathcal{A}$
is $J$-semisimple, and since it is artinian it has to be semisimple. Then I used Artin-Wedderburn to conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to $M_{n_1} (\mathbb{C}) \oplus \cdots \oplus M_{n_k} (\mathbb{C})$ as a complex algebra. But I want to show that it is also isomorphic as a $C^*$-algebra, and this is where I'm stuck. It would be enough to show that there is only one norm and involution that makes $M_{n_1} (\mathbb{C}) \oplus \cdots \oplus M_{n_k} (\mathbb{C})$ into a $C^*$-algebra, but I don't know how to do that. Is there any way to salvage my attempt at a proof?

You can avoid Artin-Wedderburn by using the GNS construction instead, which will get you the norm and involution for free. See https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/finite-noncommutative-probability-the-born-rule-and-wave-function-collapse/ for some details.

You can use GNS theorem and assume that your algebra is isometrically  isomorphic to $C^*$ subalgebra of $B(H)$ through a representation.Then use the decomposition into a direct sum of irreducible representations (which is possible due to the finite dimension of the algebra).

I think the approach in Karen Strung's book is quite informative for this theorem. happy new year.
